# O365 Mobile Device Export

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

The following code works on our internal exchange server minus the connection bits as thats not needed on-prem. I have added connection code to 365, which works fine. When I run this, I get the following error and it forces me to login a second time and exports only a fraction of the results:

```
    Starting a command on the remote server failed with the following error message : The I/O operation has been aborted
because of either a thread exit or an application request. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting
Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (ps.outlook.com:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com

Processing data from remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the following error message: WS-Management cannot
process the request. The operation failed because of an HTTP error. The HTTP error (12152) is: The server returned an
invalid or unrecognized response . For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (ps.outlook.com:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : JobFailure
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com
```

Below is the code I am attempting to use. Do I have it formatted wrong?

```
#Script Created by Daniel Taylor 8/8/18

#Set Location for export:
$fLocation = "C:\temp\"

#Get username and password for 0365 connection
$cred = get-credential

#Import microsoft online
Import-module msonline

#Connect to MSonline
connect-msolservice -Credential $cred

#Connect to exchange online
$EolSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri “https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/” -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

Import-PSSession $EolSession -DisableNameChecking

Write-host "You are now connected to Exchange. Begning ActiveSync Export:" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen

#create File to write report to:
$fName = $fLocation+"ActiveSyncDevices.txt"
$test = test-path $fName
    if ($test -eq $True)
        {
            write-host "Removing Old File..." -ForeGroundColor Red
            Remove-Item $fName
        }
    #Else
        #{
            #New-Item $fName -type file
        #}
Write-host "Creating New File..." -ForeGroundColor Green
New-Item $fName -type file

#Get ActiveSync and Mailbox data
$EASDevices = ""
$AllEASDevices = @()

$EASDevices = ""| select 'User','PrimarySMTPAddress','DeviceType','DeviceModel','DeviceOS', 'LastSyncAttemptTime','LastSuccessSync'
$EasMailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited
foreach ($EASUser in $EasMailboxes) {
$EASDevices.user = $EASUser.displayname
$EASDevices.PrimarySMTPAddress = $EASUser.PrimarySMTPAddress.tostring()
    foreach ($EASUserDevices in Get-MobileDevice -Mailbox $EasUser.alias) {
$EASDeviceStatistics = $EASUserDevices | Get-MobileDeviceStatistics
    $EASDevices.devicetype = $EASUserDevices.devicetype
    $EASDevices.devicemodel = $EASUserDevices.devicemodel
    $EASDevices.deviceos = $EASUserDevices.deviceos
$EASDevices.lastsyncattempttime = $EASDeviceStatistics.lastsyncattempttime
$EASDevices.lastsuccesssync = $EASDeviceStatistics.lastsuccesssync
    $AllEASDevices += $EASDevices | select user,primarysmtpaddress,devicetype,devicemodel,deviceos,lastsyncattempttime,lastsuccesssync
    }
    }
$AllEASDevices = $AllEASDevices | sort user
$AllEASDevices | Export-Csv $fname

write-host "The script completed successfully! The output file can be found at $fName" -ForeGroundColor Yellow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot be logged in to Exchange on-prem and Exchange online at the same time. They use the same cmdlet and on-prem will take precedence.

If you are using PSRemoting, you must use two different sessions, and it's best to prefix those, so they are unique.

Or, be on the Exchange server directly and do your thing there, and open a new PSRemoting session to O365, prefixed so that the proxied commands have the prefix name.

Then make your O365 calls with the proxied cmdlets, not the on-prem ones.

Example Session setup:

```
# Exchange PowerShell Remote Management
#
$creds = Import-Clixml -Path $CredPath 

$ExchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName 'Microsoft.Exchange' `
-ConnectionUri ('http://' + $ExchangeServerFQDN + '/PowerShell') `
-Authentication Kerberos -Credential $Creds.ExpAdmin
Import-PSSession $ExchangeSession -Prefix 'EXP'


$creds = Import-Clixml -Path $CredPath 

$ExchangeOnlineSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName 'Microsoft.Exchange' `
-ConnectionUri 'https://outlook.office365.com/PowerShell-liveid/' `
-Authentication Basic -Credential $Creds.ExoAdmin -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $ExchangeOnlineSession -Prefix 'EXO'

Get-PSSession
```

Each of the command will have EXP or EXO as part of the name of the proxied cmdlets.
Again, if you are doing this directly on Exchange, you only need the EXO session, and use the on-prem Exchange cmdlets normally.

Comment: Interesting, I have no issues running this without the connection code, on-prem. The issue is on 365 halfway through running the #Get ActiveSync and Mailbox data bit, it acts like I have to log on a second time, and throws multiple of the above error.

Comment: Yep, been there, done that, hence the approach I show above. There are others who have shown the same thing type of setup. The other thing that has hit is that the MSOL session creds seems to die off without warning, or when you pass creds to one it doesn't carry to the next. Hence you see me calling my cred file twice. I use that secure cred file to prevent having to type it again, and call it dynamically.

Comment: ah, I will give it a shot!

Comment: One other thing, we manage many teneants, how would I edit that to still prompt me for the creds, so it stores them to recall as the file does?

Comment: If you are using a the O365 delegated config for your customers, then, this could be and option. https://gcits.com/knowledge-base/export-list-office-365-users-licenses-customer-tenants-delegated-administration. Now this is only talking about export, yet, tweaking from this one, should get you where you are going.